# Custom authorization based on url in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7

I am saving url's in database and respective users are mapped to the url

```
URL: ~/user
```

From application, I am checking via

```
bool isAuthorized = DBHelper.IsAuthorized(
string.Concat("~" , Url.Action("Index", "User"), 
httpContext.User.Identity.Name);
```

It works well in development environment. But in production, application is configured under a IIS application **ucms**, so Url.Action("Index", "User") is returning `/ucms/user` hence`isAuthorized` is returning false.

Could anyone provide any inputs or direction on the changes to be done to tackle this behaviour.

Comment: Those stumble upon this question should check your previous question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840063/remove-application-name-from-url-in-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the virtual path before checking it:

```
var relativePath = yourPath.Remove(0, HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath.Length);
```

Works both for virtual dirs and domains.